# MySql query to return a random row returns unexpected number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, random, mysql-select-db

I am trying to get a random word from a long list of words in a MySql table: `word_list [id*|wword]`.

My query looks at the moment like this:

`SELECT * FROM word_list w where id =  (SELECT FLOOR(1 + RAND()*(10-1)))`

I thought the above query would return one and only one random row with Id between 1 and 9.

To my surprise it sometimes returns 0, 1, 2 or 3 rows. How is this possible?

[image: example with three returned words, inclding table definition]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's calculating a new random number for each row. When the result of the random expression matches the `id`, then that row is included in the result.

This should demonstrate how your query is working:

```
SELECT id, wword, FLOOR(1+RAND()*(10-1)) AS r FROM word_list;
```

This returns a different random number on each row (which is also what you're doing with your random expression in the WHERE clause). Sometimes the random number returned as `r` is equal to `id` on the respective row. Not often, but occasionally. When these two numbers happen to be equal, that's when a row would be returned in your query.

What you need instead is to calculate a random number *once*. For example:

```
SELECT word_list.*
FROM (SELECT FLOOR(1+RAND()*(10-1)) AS id) AS r
CROSS JOIN word_list USING (id);
```

Supposing your table is guaranteed to have one row for each `id` value between 1 and 10, this should return exactly one row.

Comment: I dont understand, doesnt `SELECT FLOOR(1 + RAND()*(10-1))` return ONE random number between 1 and 9?

Comment: It returns one random number _each time the expression is evaluated_, and in your query it's evaluated once for each row. It's like you are rolling a die for each row. Each time you get a new random value, and that value might match the `id` of the row.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution may be to order by `RAND()` than limit to 1.
This method works if your table isn't too big.

`SELECT * FROM word_list ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Thanks / thats simpler than my query and as I have only 173528 rows it seems to perform aceptable for my purpose